# Pandas: Convert Yfinance dictionary to dataframe but the row is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I have a Yfinance dictionary like this:

{'zip': '94404',
'sector': 'Healthcare',
'fullTimeEmployees': 11800,
'circulatingSupply': None,
'startDate': None,
'regularMarketDayLow': 67.99,
'priceHint': 2,
'currency': 'USD'}

I want to convert it into DataFrame but the output has no information on Row:

Jupyter Notebook view:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Data = {'zip': '94404', 'sector': 'Healthcare', 'fullTimeEmployees': 11800, 'circulatingSupply': None, 'startDate': None, 'regularMarketDayLow': 67.99, 'priceHint': 2, 'currency': 'USD'}
```

Third bracket around the dictionary variable:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([Data])
df
```

Result:

```
     zip    sector   fullTimeEmployees  circulatingSupply   startDate   regularMarketDayLow priceHint   currency
0   94404   Healthcare  11800               None              None          67.99              2         USD
```

Comment: @Janicewww Welcome! you can mark it as an answer and click the upvote on the top-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Data returned back by yfinance
stock = yf.Ticker('AAPL')

# Store stock info as dictionary
stock_dict = stock.info

# Create DataFrame from non-compatible dictionary
stock_df = pd.DataFrame(list(stock_dict.items()))


    0   1
0   zip 95014
1   sector  Technology
2   fullTimeEmployees   137000
3   longBusinessSummary Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...
4   city    Cupertino
5   phone   408-996-1010
6   country United States
7   companyOfficers []
8   website http://www.apple.com
9   maxAge  1
10  address1    One Apple Park Way
```

Comment: Hello. May I know how can I place the brackets in the data? How to add a brackets on the output?

Comment: @Janicewww I revised the answer above. The data returned to the "stock" variable by yf.Ticker is not the conventional dictionary that it appears to be. That's the reason I used ".items()" in the creation of the dataframe. This is more of a partial answer to at least get it to a dataframe. I ran into issues trying to have series 0 be the columns and series 1 as the data.